# PL/sql cursors no output for the following code

Tags: plsql, cursor

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
temp_id applicant.id%type;
cursor c1 is select id from applicant where father like 'xyz';
begin
if not c1%isopen then open c1;
end if;
loop
fetch c1 into temp_id;
dbms_output.put_line(temp_id);
exit when c1%notfound;
end loop;
close c1;
end;
/
```

i have a table applicant with an id column. I don't think the cursor fetches anything. Though the procedure is completed successfully. is there an error in the where father like 'xyz' condition?

Comment: You could add another line dbms_output.put_line('inside'); beneath the existing dbms_output, to see if you are returning any rows. If not then I'd suggest no rows are meeting the condition father like 'xyz'. Possibly you want to use lower(father) like '%xyz%' With % being the wildcard, and lower making everything in the father field lower case.

Comment: Make sure your SQL statement by itself returns rows, and as @stevo suggested make sure the case is consistent or handled, and you also need to use the % or _ wild cards appropriately. You can also output some cursor attributes to check if your cursor has returned any rows. Such as adding `dbms_output.put_line(c1%rowcount);` after the cursor is opened to get the number of rows, or even just a boolean check of `c1%found`.

Comment: @Preeti: Please try this `select id from applicant where father like '%xyz%';` ,I dnt know why you have put `like` if you don't want to use  main functionality of `like`,i mean use `%` .If you want that father name should be `xyz` ,then try  `father ='xyz'`   rather than `father like 'xyz'`

Comment: thanks guys. i figured out what the error was, stevo's comment help check whether the cursor was fetching any results or not
and finally
    father like 'xyx' was father like 'XYZ'
didn know sql was case sensitive for strings!

Comment: @Preeti .  I hear that alot.  Are there some RDBMS's that ignore case sensitivity when it comes to data in a column?  In most programming languages when comparing 'foo' to 'FOO' you have to use a special operator to ignore case.  Just was wondering if anyone else have seen this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this select id from applicant where father like '%xyz%'; ,I dnt know why you have put like if you don't want to use main functionality of like,i mean use % .If you want that father name should be xyz ,then try father ='xyz' rather than father like 'xyz'